# Query returns 1 too many rows

Tags: php, pdo

```
 class getPosts
    {
        public $post_id;  
        public $title;  
        public $content;  
        public $author;

function __construct($inPost_id=null, $inTitle=null, $inContent=null, $inAuthor=null)  
    {

 $this->post_id = $inPost_id; 
 $this->title = $inTitle; 
 $this->content = $inContent; 
 $this->author = $inAuthor; 


    }
        function getPosts() 
        {
            $postnumber = 14;
            $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $postnumber");
            $query->execute();
            $postArray = array();
            while ($row = $query->fetch())
            {
                $myPost = new getPosts($row["id"],
                    $row['title'], $row['content'],
                    $row['author'], $row["author_id"]);
                array_push($postArray, $myPost);
            }
            return $postArray;
        }
    }
```

This is working but not so well, as instead of 14 it returns 15.

Is it good to use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in `fetch()`?

Comment: What does the 15th row contain? Data? Or just blanks?

Comment: 15 posts are retrieved instead of 14

Comment: You could just set `LIMIT` to `$postnumber-1`...Bad solution, but it should work...

Comment: I'm confused as to why this isn't recursing infinitely.  The constructor for the `getPosts` class is instantiating a new `getPosts` instance for each row... which in turn is calling the constructor for the `getPosts` class, which is instantiating more instances... or is there something special about PHP 4 style constructors that prevents this from happening?  While we're at it, why is the constructor returning a value?  What am I missing here?

Comment: ohh i just not copy it in here. I edit it

Answer (score 1):

When using prepared statements you should bind any parameters:

```
$postnumber = 14;
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT :postnumber");
$query->bindParam(':postnumber', $postnumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Why i should used here since i know what $postnumber is.I use it for user input, but why here ?

Comment: If you do use it here does it fix your problem?